# How to fix "no suitable method found to override" and how to use array?

Tags: c#, arrays, overriding, console-application, console.writeline

I keep getting the error "no suitable method found to override" at the two "output". How would I fix that?

How do I use array to put the numbers 4, 5, and 6 in the first sentence and 7 in the second sentence?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication_program
{
    public class Numbers
    {
        public virtual void output()
        {

        }
    }
    public class IntegerOne : Numbers
    {
        public override void output(double o, double tw, double th)
        {
            one = o;
            two = tw;
            three = th;
        }
    }
    public class IntegerTwo : Numbers
    {
        public override void output(double f)
        {
            four = f;
        }
    }
    class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Numbers[] chosen = new Numbers[2];

            chosen[0] = new IntegerOne(4, 5, 6);
            chosen[1] = new IntegerTwo(7);


            Console.WriteLine("First number is {0}, second number is {1}, and third number is {2}", ;
            Console.WriteLine("Fourth number is {0}", ;

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those aren't considered overrides as their signatures aren't the same (ie they have different arguments).  I think you mean to put them into the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

When overriding a virtual method, the signature must match the method being overridden.

If the virtual method is:

```
virtual void Method( int a, int b ) { ... }
```

The override must also have the same parameters:

```
override void Method( int a, int b ) { ... }
```